# How to extract the points of the a referring_segment in Boost library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I have polygon in Boost , I am trying to extract the segments of the polygon and then save the points that are used to create the segment . I am using Boost library in c++.

How can I do that ?

```
typedef boost::tuple<double, double> point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point> polygon;
typedef boost::geometry::model::referring_segment<point> segment;

template<typename Segment>
void get_segments(Segment const& s) {

    std::cout << "Segment is "<<dsv(s) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Points of this segments are :";
        //Extract the points of this segment somehow


}


int main() {

    polygon poly;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt(
            "polygon((2.0 1.3, 2.4 1.7, 2.8 1.8, 3.4 1.2, 3.7 1.6, 3.4 2.0, 4.1 3.0, 5.3 2.6, 5.4 1.2, 4.9 0.8, 2.9 0.7, 2.0 1.3))",
            poly);

    polygon hull;
    boost::geometry::convex_hull(poly, hull);

    // Now I know I can `dsv()` and print to the screen like this:

    std::cout << "hull: " << dsv(hull) << std::endl;

    boost::geometry::for_each_segment(boost::geometry::exterior_ring(hull),
            get_segments<segment>);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution , I used get(segment)

```
template<typename Segment>
void get_segments(Segment const& s) {

    std::cout << "Segment is "<<dsv(s) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1st Point"<<get<0,0>(s)<<","<<get<0,1>(s)<<std::endl;
    std::cout << "2nd Point"<<get<1,0>(s)<<","<<get<1,1>(s)<<std::endl;
```